# Add toolbar dynamically to an abstract activity

Tags: android, android-activity, toolbar

I have a base activity that all of my activities extend from. This class includes basics like a toolbar and a navigation drawer.

I am looking for a solution that will allow me to override a method in extended activities so I can change the type of toolbar that activity will use.

```
public abstract class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private Toolbar mToolbar;
private FrameLayout mContentFrame;
private ActivityFragment mActivityFragment;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(setLayout());
    initViews();
    initToolbar();
}

protected int setLayout() {
    return R.layout.activity_base;
}

//I want to override this and provide a different toolbar layout!
protected int setToolbarLayout(){
    return R.layout.toolbar;
}

protected void initViews() {
    mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    mContentFrame = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.contentFrame);
}

private void initToolbar() {
    setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        mToolbar.setElevation(10f);
    }
}

protected void setContentFragment(ActivityFragment fragment) {
    FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    transaction.replace(getContentFrame().getId(), fragment).commit();
    supportInvalidateOptionsMenu();
    this.mActivityFragment = fragment;
    setTitle(fragment.getTitle(this));
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
            return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

public Toolbar getToolbar() {
    return mToolbar;
}

public FrameLayout getContentFrame() {
    return mContentFrame;
}

public ActivityFragment getActivityFragment() {
    return mActivityFragment;
}
```

I have tried inflating the toolbar after setContentView() and setting the actionbar to it but it appeared with no icons or widgets!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok everyone (whoever it concerns) I figured it out. All I had to do was inflate my contentView prior to calling setContentView(). Once I have that inflated I add the inflated toolbar view!

```
public abstract class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private Toolbar mToolbar;
private FrameLayout mContentFrame;
private ActivityFragment mActivityFragment;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(inflateLayout());
    initViews();
    initToolbar();
}

protected int getLayoutRes(){
    return R.layout.activity_base;
}

protected int getToolbarLayout(){
    return R.layout.toolbar;
}

private View inflateLayout() {
    View contentView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(getLayoutRes(), null, false);
    attachToolbarToLayout(getLayoutInflater(), (ViewGroup) contentView);
    return contentView;
}

private void attachToolbarToLayout(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup parent){
    mToolbar = (Toolbar) inflater.inflate(getToolbarLayout(),parent,false);
    parent.addView(mToolbar,0);
}

protected void initViews() {
    mContentFrame = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.contentFrame);
}

private void initToolbar() {
    setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        mToolbar.setElevation(10f);
    }
}

protected void setContentFragment(ActivityFragment fragment) {
    FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    transaction.replace(getContentFrame().getId(), fragment).commit();
    supportInvalidateOptionsMenu();
    this.mActivityFragment = fragment;
    setTitle(fragment.getTitle(this));
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
            return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

public Toolbar getToolbar() {
    return mToolbar;
}

public FrameLayout getContentFrame() {
    return mContentFrame;
}

public ActivityFragment getActivityFragment() {
    return mActivityFragment;
}
```

Comment: it's nice, but you have made unnecessary method making the code complicated to understand.